# To show a holomorphic map on the open unit disk is Constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Q. Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on the unit disk $\mathbf{D}$ such that $|f(z)|\rightarrow 1$ as $|z|\rightarrow 1$, and suppose $f(z)\neq 0 \hspace{1ex}\forall z$. Show that $f$ is constant.

Using maximum principle we get $|f(z)|\leq 1$. Now if $1$ is attained we get $f$ is constant. So,we can assume $f:\mathbf{D} \rightarrow \mathbf{D}$. Then  how to proceed? I tried to compose f with an automorphism of $\mathbf{D}$ and applied Schwartz lemma, didn't help much.

Comment: Do you mean $|f(z)|=1$ for every z with $|z|\rightarrow 1$? If so then since $f(z)\neq 0$, we must also have $\frac{1}{|f(z)|}\leq 1$ i.e. $|f(z)| \geq 1$ and equality follows.

Comment: I think it's clear. As $z\rightarrow$ some point in $S^1, f(z)\rightarrow $ some point in $S^1$

Comment: @Diger would you explain a bit more what you want to say

Comment: I think it's clear. ;)

Comment: Well you already started with $f$ must obey maximum principle, but $f(z)\neq 0$ then also $1/f$ must obey the maximum principle.

Comment: Oh... I see it. nice thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $|f|$ attains a minimum somewhere.

Comment: Can you explain a bit.. I can't really see it.

Comment: $\frac{1}{f}$ satisfies same conditions as $f$