# Let $D = D(0,1)$, $f$ holomorphic on $D$, continuous on its closure, $f(z) \neq 0$. Then, if $|f(z)|=1$ on $|z| =1$, $f$ is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $D = D(0,1)$, $f$ holomorphic on $D$, continuous on its closure, $f(0) \neq 0$. Then, if $|f(z)|=1$ on $|z| =1$, $f$ is constant.

My guess here is to extend $f$ outside $D$ with the constant $1$, and then apply Liouville's theorem. Is it a correct approach?

Edit: I misread the question, it's $f(z) \neq 0$ and not $f(0) \neq 0$.
Still, I'm kinda lost.

Comment: You can't just extend $f$ with $1$ outside the unit disc and expect the result to be holomorphic.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought, but then I am kinda clueless, any other ideas?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3182285/to-show-a-holomorphic-map-on-the-open-unit-disk-is-constant/3182314#comment6550152_3182314

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't prove it, since it is false. Take$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&D(0,1)&\longrightarrow&D(0,1)\\&z&\mapsto&\dfrac{z-\frac12}{1-\frac z2}.\end{array}$$

---

Now, an answer to the **new** version of the question is: $f$ must have a minimum (since $\overline{D(0,1)}$ is compact). So, all you have to do is to apply the minimum principle.

Comment: Yeah, you are totally right, in fact I edited the question since I misread it!

Comment: See the edited answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just knew of the maximum principle and not the minimum principle, but the idea is kinda the same!