# $f$ be holomorphic on $\mathbb{D}$, continuous on > $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ s.t $|f(z)|=1$ whenever $|z|=1$.

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

> Let $f$ be holomorphic on $\mathbb{D}$, continuous on
> $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ s.t $|f(z)|=1$ whenever $|z|=1$. Prove that if
> $f(z)\neq 0$ for all $z\in\mathbb{D}$ then $f$ is constant on
> $\mathbb{D}$.

I already proved the following result:

Let $f$ be non-constant, holomorphic on $\mathbb{D}$, continuous on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ s.t $|f(z)|=1$ whenever $|z|=1$. Then there exists $z_0\in\mathbb{D}$ s.t $f(z_0)=0.$

I don't know whether this could help me solve the actual problem? Could someone give me any idea?

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3182285/to-show-a-holomorphic-map-on-the-open-unit-disk-is-constant) help?

Comment: The statement you want to prove is the contrapositive of the statement you have already proven ...

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$F(z)=\frac{1}{f(z)},\quad z\in\overline{\mathbb D},$$
then $F$  holomorphic on $\mathbb{D}$, continuous on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$, and $|F(z)|=1$ whenever $|z|=1$.
So $|F(z)|$ attains its minimum at some point
$z_0\in\overline{\mathbb D}$.

If $|z_0|=1$, then $|F(z)|\equiv1$ on $\overline{\mathbb D}$ and $F\equiv C$;

If $|z_0|<1$, then $$|f(z_0)|=\max_{z\in\overline{\mathbb D}}|f(z)|.$$
maximum modulus principle implies $f$ is constant!