# If $f$ is an non-null entire function that satisfies $|f(z)|=2$ for all $z\in\partial \Bbb D$, then $f$ is constant?

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

I want to prove if either this statement is true or false:

> Let $f:\Bbb C\to \Bbb C$ be a non-null entire function which verifies that $|f(z)|=2$ for every $z$ that belongs in the circle of center the origin and radius 1 ($\partial\Bbb D$, where $\Bbb D$ is the closed unit disc). Then $f$ is constant.

I tried starting with the maximum and minimum module princiles to prove it, but I got nowhere. I also tried looking for a counterexample, but I found nothing as well.

Could anyone please help me out?

EDIT: I understand that there is an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222509/proving-fz-is-constant-on-the-boundary-of-a-domain-implies-f-is-a-consta), but this is for bounded functions. Would it still work for non-bounded functions?

Comment: But that $f$ doesn't work because $f(0)=0$, and $f$ is non-null.

Comment: Re your edit: The other Q&A is about holomorphic functions in a bounded domain, not about bounded functions. You can apply that solution directly to your case.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for the clarification!