# Understanding a small step in the proof of Maximum Modulus Principle in ProofWiki

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

Consider the given proof of the Maximum Modulus Principle in [ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Maximum_Modulus_Principle). This is really just a minor question, but the given proof says that

> However, since this this holds for all sufficiently small $r > 0$, $|f|$ would be constant in $B_r(z)$.

Is the proof trying to say that the supposed equality holds for all $0 < r' \leq r$ by repeated application of the mean value property of holomorphic functions or is there a reason why we'd need to make some special choice for $0 < r' \leq r$?

Comment: Where did you get inequalities of r?

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom My understanding was that that once we suppose that $|f(z)| = \max_{\theta \in [0, 2\pi)}|f(z + r\exp(i\theta))|$ for a fixed $r > 0$, we reapply the mean value property for all $0 < r' \leq r$. But I just started to wonder about the exact wording of the proof, namely that does the "sufficiently small" convey the same main idea.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222509/proving-fz-is-constant-on-the-boundary-of-a-domain-implies-f-is-a-consta)

Comment: Fairly certain this proof is wrong, check another resource (5/20/23)